# I get a notification every day that says " Couldn't send attachments Photo's"

Tags: notifications

When I click on the notification it opens gmail. I am not trying to send any thing, I have made sure my outbox and drafts are empty. Is some other program trying to send out my pictures? How do I stop this?

Comment: If you long press the notification and click `App info` what does it say. It could be something invoking gmail to send this mail.

Answer (score 1):

You can go into GMail and look for outstanding mails in your outbox directory and delete them.

If that doesn't work/there is no mail you can go into settings > apps > gmail > wipe app data/clear data.
Then GMail has been factory reset.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue on my Android phone and found the solution: Whatever document I was trying to attach, has become either corrupt or no longer exist. That is why I was facing issue. I copied a fresh document into my mobile storage and was able to attach it with gmail id. 
Hope this will help you.